# Изменить список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Есть списки `a` и `b`:

```
a = array([12, 71, 121, 163, 200, 243, 259])
b = array([139, 132 135, 131, 137, 132, 134])
```

`a` соответвует порядковому номеру значения в списке, а `b` - значение которое приходится на этот номер.

Как из `a` и `b` получить:

```
с = [...0, 0, 0, 139, 0, 0, 0, .....0, 0, 0, 132, 0, 0, 0, ...]
```

где 139 находится в списке под номером 12, а 132 - под номером 71?

Comment: своих идей совсем никаких? Как сделать это на листке бумаги карандашом?

Comment: `c = [0] * (max(a) + 1); for i, j in zip(a, b): c[i] = j;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def fun(a, b):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.asarray(b)
    res = np.full(a.max() + 1, fill_value=np.nan)
    res[a] = b
    return res.tolist()
```

результат:

```
In [222]: fun([3, 5, 8], [10, 11, -3])
Out[222]: [nan, nan, nan, 10.0, nan, 11.0, nan, nan, -3.0]
```

Comment: @Valent, исправил на `nan`. По поводу второго вопроса - это нужно видеть полный `error traceback`

Comment: @Valent, преобразуйте списки в numpy.array - `a = np.array(a); ...`, а потом преобразуйте результат в список: `res = res.tolist()`

Comment: @Valent Вы принципиально не хотите пользоваться `Numpy`? Сделать то можно, но код будет сложнее

Comment: @Valent И ещё непонятно - зачем вам питоновский список с нумпаевским `np.nan`? Что-то одно - либо список с `None`, либо `numpy.array` с `np.nan`, а так это помесь ужа с ежом.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а зачем вы удалили свой ответ? я еще не успел за него проголосовать! :)

Comment: @MaxU Я перенёс этот ответ в новый вопрос, заданный автором )